# What is the highest RDP protocol version implemented by Remmina/FreeRDP?

Tags: linux, windows-10, remote-desktop, remmina

What is the highest [RDP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) version implemented by [Remmina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remmina) or the underlying [FreeRDP software](http://www.freerdp.com/)? I cannot seem to find any details on the official website of either project?

I am looking to repurpose some old laptops by installing a small Linux distro plus Remmina to allow them to remote desktop to a Windows 10 PC.  I'm aware that Windows Server 2012 (equivalent to Windows 8) [requires a Remote Desktop client supporting RDP Protocol 6 or later](https://serverfault.com/questions/503649/what-is-the-minimum-version-of-rdp-supported-by-server-2012-rds). Therefore I'm afraid connecting to Windows 10 will require a minimum of RDP Protocol 6 or later. That is why I'm asking the hightest RDP protocol supported by Remmina/FreeRDP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FreeRDP [supports AVC](http://pub.freerdp.com/api/struct__RDPGFX__AVC444__BITMAP__STREAM.html) which was [introduced in RDP version 10](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-security-and/remote-desktop-protocol-rdp-10-avc-h-264-improvements-in-windows/ba-p/249588) it should be compatible with RDP version 10. But as with all proprietary protocols mileage may vary. Using AVC444 or AVC420 you should be able to connect (eg. /gfx:AVC444).

Initial support was [added Jul 2, 2014](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/commit/4d3d78c48799dbce9f1d6aa827aa5a884992476f#diff-b67f117e934cfb801bd2c2a5112e9548) so chances are high everything works today. According to the source code of [gcc.c](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/blob/c367f65d42e0d2e1ca248998175180aa9c2eacd0/libfreerdp/core/gcc.c#L73) and [settings.h](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/blob/2d715e4681b92108d012fede181fd0a9b401e7e3/include/freerdp/settings.h#L83) FreeRDP appears to be compatible up to RDP version 10.7.
The support was added on [Dec 19, 2019](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/commit/323491dab108dcd759bf0a3323800285f9bd9aff) and was first available in FreeRDP release 2.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Remmina/FreeRDP can connect to all versions of Windows,
including Windows 10, so supporting all versions of the RDP protocol.

Strangely enough, the projects themselves don't list specific Windows versions,
but many articles discuss connecting from Linux to Windows 10.

One example is
[How to connect to a remote desktop from Linux](https://opensource.com/article/18/6/linux-remote-desktop):

> Remmina's minimal UI makes it easy to remotely access Linux PCs and Windows 10.

Note that RDP is not supported in Windows 10 Home. If this is your case, see also
[tutorial for installing Reminna and using RDP with Windows 10 Home](https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/tutorials/tutorial-for-installing-reminna-and-using-rdp-with-windows10-home/).

Answer (score 2):

I found no direct information on the association *Version of Remmina* <-> *Version of FreeRDP* <-> *Version of RDP*.

But I found the following pieces of information:

1. Free RDP lib >= 2.0.0-rc2 supports H264 [ref](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/1678).
2. Remmina 1.2.30.1 supports Free RDP lib >= 2.0.0-rc2 [ref](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/1678).
3. Support for H264 [was added in RDP version 10.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol), the latest (important for video compression).

So Remmina 1.2.30.1 would be enough to connect with the latest RDP version.